# Granting Service Account Access to "Family" Calendar

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

TL/DR Is it possible to grant a service account access to the auto-generated Family calendar?

Adding a service account to a google calendar is usually achieved by adding the service account in the **Share with specific people** card in the calendar setting.

On a Family calendar, which is created when one creates a family at https://families.google.com/families that card is replaced by a **Permissions settings** card which states *Events added to this calendar will be shared with all family members.* with a link to manage family membership.

I have tried adding the service account to the family membership page but that is not granting the explicit permissions that one typically sees with a service account.

Comment: Did you check the [Creating a service account guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)? There are process like 'grant G-suite domain-wide authority'

Comment: @noogui Thanks for the suggestion. I enabled domain-wide authority but that still doesn't grant access to the family calendar.

Comment: @Declan_K Did you ever figure out how to do this?